# Spring MVC | Load Environment specific Property Files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, properties, production-environment

I'm working a Spring MVC project (version > 4.x). This is not a Spring Boot project.
I need to have a mechanism where I can maintain environment specific folders such as 'DEV', 'PROD', 'UAT" etc. Each one of these folders will have properties specific to that specific environment.
I have configured my PropertiesPlaceholder as under:

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:application-default.properties, classpath:application-${env}.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

My properties are defined as under:

```
-src
 -main
  -Resources
   -Properties
    -application-dev.properties
    -application-prod.properties
```

I want the placeholder ${env} to get resolved at runtime so that only the properties relevant to that environment should be read by the propertyplaceholder.

I would love to hear your comments and the best practices around it. In higher environments, we will have a Jenkins pipeline doing th ebuilds for us.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to change properties file as per the profile. So you can do that by putting the following lines in your web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Just use the standard names allowing by Spring and it will pick appropriate `.properties` file. Also you cna use following piece of command while starting application.The profile names passed as the parameter will be activated during application start-up.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```